# How to loop and provide limits on numbers that are allowed and not

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, logic

I need help..
I want to "looping" the same as the image attached, what's the logic of the repetition?

Thanks in advance good people :)

example output

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use for loop:

```
let output = "";

for (let i=0; i <= 9; i++) {
   for (let j=0; j <= 9; j++) {
       output += i;
       output += j;
       output += '*';
   }
}

console.log(output);
```

Comment: Oke, but how to make output looping like this image ?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkCLO.png

Comment: Was the solution as you wanted? if so please mark it as solved.